# Accessing huge volumes of data from Facebook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-fql, facebook-opengraph, fb-graph

So I am working on a Rails application, and the person I am designing it for has what seem like extremely hefty data volume requirements.  They want to gather ALL posts by a user that logs into the application, and all of the posts for each of their friends for the past year.

Before this particular level of detail was communicated to me, I built the thing using the fb_graph gem and would paginate through posts.  I am running into the fact that first it takes a very long time to do this, even when I change the number of posts requested per page.  Second, I frequently run into the Oauth error #613, more than 600 requests per 600 seconds.  After increasing each request to 200 posts I run into this limit less, but it still takes an incredibly long time to get all of this data.

I am not particularly familiar with the FQL alternative, but it seems to me that we are going to have to either prioritize speed or volume of data.  Is there a way that I am missing that would allow me to quickly retrieve this level of information?

Edit: I do save all posts to the database as I retrieve them.  What is required is to make one pass through and grab all of the posts for the past year, for the user and friends.  This process takes a long time and I am basically wondering if there is any way that it can be sped up.

Comment: Maybe the [koala](https://github.com/arsduo/koala) gem does do things a little differently. Might be worth checking different options, though this is more of a sidenote. It's considered to be very good from what I've heard.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that I'd like to point out here:
You should implement some kind of local caching for user's posts. I mean, instead of querying FB each time for the posts, you should save the posts in your local database and only check for new posts (whenever needed).

This is faster and saves you many API requests.

Comment: I guess I should clarify - I do this already.  He wants to download and save all users posts.  It just takes a hell of a long time and a hell of a lot of requests.  Its more the first time through, requesting all of this data, that is the problem.